# How to group files into groups of some size in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, file, group-by

Imagine you have 10 files which I need to send, for example:

**$files** of type string[]

- 1.jpg - 3.2MB
- 2.jpg - 2.8MB
- 3.jpg - 3.5MB
- 4.jpg - 2.1MB
- 5.jpg - 0.9MB
- 6.jpg - 2.9MB
- 7.jpg - 2.4MB
- 8.jpg - 2.1MB
- 9.jpg - 1.1MB
- 10.jpg - 1.9MB

Also I have for example 10MB limit per one e-mail. **$limit**

1. I need to create groups of files (arrays or filenames) where each group has filenames of files which filesize sum is lower than **$limit**
   Example:

   - ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'] - **WRONG (11.6MB > $limit)**
   - ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'] - **OK (9.5MB < $limit)**
2. Even better to has as few groups as possible (for example you can have 10 groups with only one file which would make this task done, but it would be better to has only few groups with more files as close to **$limit** as possible)

I need to do this with pure PHP or with a help of Laravel if needed

Thanks

UPDATE:
**I know how to get file size**, I need to group those files

Comment: Hint: This kind of problems are known for `Bin Packing Problem`.

Comment: On top of @HarunYilmaz's hint => an example of an algo (but not in php) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/

Answer (score 1):

We can [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) that to find *as few groups as possible* *is a combinatorial NP-hard problem*, but with an algorithm such as *First Fit Decreasing* we get results that should be good enough. Here's an example implementation:

```
$files = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg');
$sizes = array(3.2, 2.8, 3.5, 2.1, 0.9, 2.9, 2.4, 2.1, 1.1, 1.9);
$limit = 10;
$files = array_combine($files, $sizes);
# algorithm "First Fit Decreasing"
arsort($files); # sort the files by descending size
$groups = array();
foreach ($files as $file => $size)
{   # insert the files one by one
    # so that each is placed in the first group that still has enough space
    foreach ($groups as &$group)
        if (array_sum($group)+$size <= $limit)
        { $group[$file] = $size; continue 2; }
    # if there is not enough space in any of the groups that are already open,
    # open a new one
    $groups[][$file] = $size; 
}
unset($group);
# the filenames are the keys within each group
foreach ($groups as $group) print_r(array_keys($group));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find methods for file type input: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Testing/File.html

To know the size of a file you can use this method:

```
$img_size = $request->file('file')->getSize();
```

You already have the most important thing, now it will depend on you how to program the solution ;)

I hope I've helped

PD: sorry for my English

Comment: I know how to get file size